# Disabling certain language translations on build

Tags: android

I have a project that depends on another library I made. Both have crowdsourced translations, which I update periodically. In most cases, I will only add translations per project when they are complete. However, it may be that one project has translations that another language does not. In this case, I'd like to strip that translation in the production app. Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: I would just rename or remove the strings.xml temporarily...

Comment: Is there a good way to do so with proguard or gradle? I'd like to avoid having to delete everything, build, and then copy over.

Comment: Just found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31575332/10317684) seems working

Comment: If I look [deeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566270/force-locale-for-android-flavor-with-resconfig) into the post it looks like the user still had some issues. The configs are cumulative, and they ended up with a hack on overriding local selections